# How would I use a browser as a GUI for Emacs apps?

Tags: web-applications, gui, emacs

I've started using Emacs, and love it. Naturally, I'm thinking about ways of extending it. I' m particularly fascinated by the thought of creating browser based GUIs for some stuff I would otherwise do in emacs, particularly reviewing fairly static data.

An example: I have a bunch of txt files (created and edited in Emacs) containing quotes and passages from my favorite books. It would be cool to present them in a more visually striking/engaging manner. For example with unique color schemes and typefaces for different authors, and several columns of text to use more screen real estate (like in [Stanza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexcycle_Stanza), the .epub reader).

Are there simpler ways of rendering HTML derived from plain text files that are open in Emacs than browsers?

Comment: Firefox was edited out and replaced by `browser`. That was a valid edit because there's nothing in your question to tie it to Firefox. If there are reasons (i.e. you like XUL), then please specify them in the question.

Comment: Do you know [Org mode](http://orgmode.org/)? It can export data from plain text files [into various other formats](http://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting.html#Exporting) including HTML.

Comment: Hi Tor, calls for lists of examples tend to do poorly here because that's all that people focus on and the question winds up attracting low-quality answers: I've edited that part out. Your other question is on-topic here though, I think.

Comment: actually sounds like font-lock-mode might be an option to solve the problem in emacs

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Markdown or other such wiki-like markup languages would be useful.  Emacs could display those in visually pleasing manners.